# Span figure in 2-column page

Tags: graphics, minipage, multicol

I would like to create a figure that contains 4 mini figures, which spans the whole 2-column page. However, the figures are shown on one half of the page only. (photo attached) I want to do a 2x2 figures that is centered across the whole page.

```
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.47\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Diagram/12.jpg}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{\fill} % note: no blank line here
    \begin{minipage}{0.47\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Diagram/346.jpg}
    \end{minipage}

    \vspace*{1cm} % vertical separation

    \begin{minipage}{0.47\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Diagram/78.jpg}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{\fill} % note: no blank line here
    \begin{minipage}{0.47\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Diagram/59.jpg}
    \end{minipage}
\caption{Figure caption goes here} \label{fig:4pics}
\end{figure}
```

[image: ss]

Comment: Figures spanning both columns in  two-column mode are obtained by means of the `figure*` environment.

Comment: Another solution, if you want to place your figures anywhere in the text, is with the `strip` environment, from the `cuted` package, which temporarily leaves the two-column mode.

Comment: ```\begin{figure*}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Diagram/ed.jpg}\par 
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Diagram/ed.jpg}\par 
    \end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Diagram/ed.jpg}\par
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Diagram/ed.jpg}\par
\end{multicols}
\caption{caption here}
\end{figure*}
``` I did this but the whole figure occupies the whole page, with a lot of white space around. May i know how to put text around it?

Comment: Don't use `multicols` within `figure*`. But your chance of getting a proper answer will greatly increase if you post some minimal code. Use `example-image` as dummy picture. Right now we don't even know which document class you are using so we can only guess.

Comment: This seems to have been superseded by the newer question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/575382 .  If that is true, this question should probably be closed.  (You can do that yourself if you agree.)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is actually duplicate to to your [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575382/wrap-text-around-figure) asked few hour latter (both about two year ago). In both question you not provide any information for which you were asked in comments nor give any information if you already solve your problem. So you left us to guessing what is your problem.

As addition to the nice *@Simon Dispa* answer (+1) here is shown one more possibilities haw can be solved your problem:

- document has defined two columns by `\documentclass` option `twocolumn`
- figure can be on the top of the next page or
  if requested at the top or bottom of the same page where is inserted
- figure occupy more fraction of page as is default set
- images haven't own sub captions and can be organized in table:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%
\usepackage{stfloats}   % if you like to have figure on the same page where 
                        % is inserted (if on the page is sufficient space)
\renewcommand{\dblfloatpagefraction}{.88}   % fraction of page reserved for floats

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{figure*}[b]  % remove option[b] if you like to have image on top of page
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} XX @{}}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}   &   \includegraphics{example-image-b}   \\[6pt]
\includegraphics{example-image-a}   &   \includegraphics{example-image-b}   
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{Figure caption goes here} 
\label{fig:4pics}
    \end{figure*}
\lipsum[12-13]
\end{document}
```

[image]

- Note: size of `figure*` in above MWE is bigger than is anticipated in `article` document by default, so fraction devoted for floats is increased by command `\renewcommand{\dblfloatpagefraction}{.88}` added to document preamble.
- If on the page is sufficient space float `figure*` without any option will be pushed on the top of the same page, otherwise on the top on the next page (standard LaTeX behavior, when is not used `stfloats` package).
  _ If you like that ˙figure*`be placed at the bottom of page, than just add option`[b]` as is done in above MWE.
- Be aware, that with option `[b]` when is not sufficient space on the page, figure will be pushed to bottom of the next page.
- I don't know, if this answer help you (you are not active on site more than one and half year) but I hope that it may help someone else with similar problem.