# Wrap text around figure

Tags: minipage, two-column, wrapfigure

I have a two-column page and am trying to fit a 2x2 figure that span across the page.

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.47\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Diagram/12.jpg}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{\fill} % note: no blank line here
    \begin{minipage}{0.47\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Diagram/346.jpg}
    \end{minipage}

    \vspace*{1cm} % vertical separation

    \begin{minipage}{0.47\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Diagram/78.jpg}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{\fill} % note: no blank line here
    \begin{minipage}{0.47\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Diagram/59.jpg}
    \end{minipage}
\caption{Figure caption goes here} \label{fig:4pics}
\end{figure*}
```

I want my text to fill around the empty space on the page. (photo attached) Could you please help?
[image]

Comment: You figure is probably over `\topfraction\textheight` and is being converted to a [p] float.  Try `\def\topfraction{0.9}` and `\def\textfraction{0.1}` or so.  Or use [ht!].

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which we can copy and test on our computers and which reproduce your problem. Without knowing page layout of the your document and image size, we can only guess what is the problem. So far the only reasonable suggestion is given in @JohnKormylo comment.

Comment: What you mean with *around of image*? That on page is alo some text or that text is alo on the left /right sides of figure?

Answer (score 2):

This is one possible solution, using `multicol`. End `multicol`, insert the figure you already built in the selected place, then start `multicol` again. Note the gap before the last section to guide the reader eye.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \section{Introduction}
    1-2 \kant[1-2]
    \section{Method}    
    3.7.    \kant[3-7]
\end{multicols}

\begin{figure*}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.47\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-A}
    \end{minipage}
        \hspace{\fill} % note: no blank line here
    \begin{minipage}{0.47\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-B}
    \end{minipage}

    \vspace*{1cm} % vertical separation

    \begin{minipage}{0.47\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-C}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{\fill} % note: no blank line here
    \begin{minipage}{0.47\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Figure caption goes here} \label{fig:4pics}
\end{figure*}   

\begin{multicols}{2}   
\section{Conclusion}
The result is shown in figure~\ref{fig:4pics}   

11-12. \kant[11-12]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image: out2]

Depending on the space left in the page, the figure will go to the top of the next page or stay in the current page.

[image: cc]